# Query Regarding SharedPreference

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I'm new to Android technology and i'm facing one problem in SharedPreference.

Actually,the problem comes when i reboot or forcely kill my Application the values stored in sharedPreference will get vanished when i again login the application i cant find the last transaction values(before killing the App).So Is there any simple way to PERSIST the sharedPreference values?Please Help me out.

Here is my code where im creating and retrieving SharedPreference

Creating SharedPreference:

```
Set<String> ordset = new HashSet<String>();
ordset.addAll(selected_ord);

sharedOrderdata = getSharedPreferences("Selected_Order", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor ed = sharedOrderdata.edit();
ed.putStringSet("Key_Ord", ordset);
ed.commit();
```

Retrieving SharedPreference:

```
Set<String> ordset = new HashSet<String>();
System.out.println("Came to OrederList  IF");

sharedData = getSharedPreferences("Selected_Order", MODE_PRIVATE);
ordset = sharedData.getStringSet("Key_Ord", null);
```

Comment: please show some code

Comment: It should not. Shared prefences are used to persist information, which do no wipe out on app kill or reboot until and unless you uninstall you app.

Comment: There must be something going wrong, show us the relevant code.

Comment: @Murtaza But it is happening with me...

Comment: After `ed.putStringSet("Key_Ord", ordset);` you are clearing it `ed.clear()`

Comment: If you want to clear your old prefrences, do `ed.clear().` before putting it.

Comment: For testing purpose only i have written that...but if we will remove it then also same scenario@MurtazaHussain

Answer (score 0):

You have to call

```
ed.apply();
```

to save your preferences.